# select data given condition on Max(date)

Tags: sql, vertica

Hi I have a simple question: select data from a table where date >= max(date) - 7.

There are many ways to do it: (Let's say the table is A)
for example: A right outer join (select max(date) from A) B on A.date >= B.date -7

But if the A table is very big, I don't want make a huge join here, the query will take long time. Are there any other way to do it?

Comment: What do you need from Table A that you need to join it?

Comment: Assume every column. But it doesnt matter.  Just a general question.

Comment: Then there is no other way but for the query to go to table A and scan it to match your query with MAX DATE.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the `join`.  Basically, you need to scan the table twice, once to get the max date and once to get the original rows.

The `join` itself is to a single row, and there is little overhead in joining to a single row.

If you knew that you had only one record per day, you could use `limit`.  But that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Is there any way could use max date from 1st scan in where clause directly?

Comment: @yabchexu . . . How?  It doesn't know what the maximum is when it reads the first row.

Comment: it seems that has to use join

Answer (score 0):

If you are really concerned about performance on a large table and this is a frequently run query I'd add the max date to an audit table which gets updated on each load. Then partition on the date in the main table so the BETWEEN max(date) and max(date) - 7 from the audit table is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using a `join` for this scenario.   Why not use a subquery?

```
Select * from A where A.date >= (select max(date) from A);
```

I assume the query plan would first evaluate the subwuery, and then use that result to filter on A.  Also, if you create a projection for this table where it is sorted by Date this should help performance.

Comment: not sure which db you are using. but for some db, aggregate function in subquery cannot refer to columns outer query.